# Iterate starting from a preset position and continue iterating after end is reached

Tags: c#, linq, for-loop, foreach

I have seen a similar example with loops continuing after the last element to reset to first, which is great. However, I am unable to figure out how to add that PLUS start iterating from a specified index of the `IList` object.

Assume we have this `IList` object with a count of 6. (To simplify I'm only using indices below instead of the full objects.)

`[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`

Now assume we need to iterate over this `IList` 10 times.

`=> Iterate 10 times`

The expected output based on the above should be:

`=> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4`

However I'd like to start iterating from #4 for example, so the expected output should now be:

`=> 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1`

(All the numbers above represent **the position** of the elements in the collection, not the actual objects as ints)

Any ideas on how this is possible with LINQ and C#? Please keep in mind that we're working with an `IList`.

Comment: @Sweeper Correct. Sorry

Comment: `list.Skip(n).Concat(list.Take(n))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest implementing an *extension method* for looping again and again:

```
// Let it be general case with IEnumerable<T>
public static class EnumerableExtensions {
  public static IEnumerable<T> Loop<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source) {
    if (null == source)
      throw new ArgumentNullException(name(source));

    List<T> list = new List<T>();

    foreach (var item in source) {
      yield return item;

      list.Add(item);
    }

    // ist.Count > 0 - we can't loop (again and again) over empty list
    for (int i = 0; list.Count > 0; i = (i + 1) % list.Count)
      yield return list[i]; 
  }
}
```

Then you can put

```
 List<int> myList = ...

 // we start looping infinitely - Loop()
 // but take first 10 items only - Take(10) 
 foreach (var item in myList.Loop().Take(10)) {
   ...
 }

 // we start looping infinitely - Loop()
 // skip first 4 items - Skip(4)
 // then take 11 items only - Take(11) 
 foreach (var item in myList.Loop().Skip(4).Take(11)) {
   ...
 }
```

Comment: A very elegant solution, will try this today. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could write the following extension method:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Iterate<T>(this IList<T> input, int from, int length)
    {
        for(int i = from; i < from + length; i++)
        {
            yield return input[i % input.Count];
        }
    }
}
```

The modulo division makes sure that you start at 0 again if your index is bigger than the size of the list.

Online demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Geqslv

Comment: You forgot the edge case where the list is empty :)

Comment: This is left as an exercise for the reader (as well as the edge cases when the list is null, when from is smaller than 0, when length is smaller than zero, when from + length is bigger than int.MaxValue, ...)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Skip` to skip required number of first elements.
For example:

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetRolledItems<T>(IList<T> source, int count, int startIndex)
{
  return Enumerable.Repeat(source, (count + startIndex) / source.Count() + 1)
    .SelectMany(a => a)
    .Skip(startIndex)
    .Take(count);
}
```

Comment: Hello, could you please explain how this works exactly?

Comment: `Enumerable.Repeat` gives you `source` multiple times - to get enough I take required count add startIndex as shift and divide it by number of items in source and add 1 to be sure it's rounded up. Then `SelectMany` will turn `Enumerable<IList<T>>` into `Enumerable<T>`, and at last we simply `Skip` first `StartIndex` elements and `Take` required `count` elements.